# Not include certain folders in a continuous deployment with TFS (Skip Command?)

Tags: tfsbuild, webdeploy, continuous-deployment

Using Team Foundation Server continuous deployment with Web Depoly, is it possible to stop certain folders being deployed? And if it is, how?

**UPDATE**
You can't specify a skip rule via the command line (as in, an MSBuild Argument) [because they are declared as items, not properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982061/msbuild-command-line-parameter-for-skipping-the-directory)

A [skip command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) can be specified in a publish profile. However it seems [publish profiles are only for the inbuilt publishing in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890289/how-do-i-configure-msbuild-to-use-a-saved-publishprofile-for-webdeploy), not Web Deploy 3.

Is there a way for Web Deploy to accept a publish profile, and if there is, should this be checked into TFS?

Comment: See my comment in Richards answer

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are confusing the *MSDeploy* command line with executing *MSBuild* via the command line.

If you are executing msdeploy.exe or the generated *deploy.cmd* file, MSBuild doesn't even come into it and you are free to use the [MSDeploy Skip Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) (you can append additional command line arguments to the *cmd* call and they will be passed to msdeploy.exe).

If you are using MSBuild + "DeployOnBuild" or MSBuild + publish profiles you will need to declare your skip requirements as `MsDeploySkipRules` items. If you're building your package separately before this point and want to deploy it, [you're going to run into some roadblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683243/deploying-an-existing-package-using-publish-profiles).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using the second option: TFS build definitions (MSBuild.exe on TFS agent server) with DeployOnBuild pointing at Web Deploy service on hosting server. I will have detailed look at your answer in the other question.

Comment: Yes this is correct. For TFS follow these steps: 1. Create a publish profile in VS 2. Edit the .pubxml file to add the skip directives 3. Check in the files 4. Create a new build definition and pass in the following for MSBuild args /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<name-of-profile> /p:<password> and any other properties you need.

Comment: @marvc1 - If you are using MSBuild, you can use publish profiles (assuming you're running VS2012 or VS2010 + Azure SDK), so declaring an item won't be a problem.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi thank you, that was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, however found that there is switch you can use that does not require a profile. Having said that, a profile has other benefits. 
Here is the argument I used that works

/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true